# Maintain the selected tab after postback MCV4 Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a page with two partialviews. One for a submit form and one for a datatable. Each partialview is a tab-pane within the tab-container. I'm using [Grid.Mvc](http://gridmvc.codeplex.com/) in the datatable's partialview so it's handling all the paging properly. The problem I have is that when I page through the grid the page returns to the first tab. I found a couple of solutions for MVC but neither seem to work below is my page with jquery. Any help would be appreciated.

Index.cshtml

```
 <p class="hiddenData"><asp:HiddenField ID="hdnData" runat="server" /></p>
       <div class="tab-container">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li><a href="#sky-form" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> File Upload</a></li>
                <li><a href="#datagrid" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span> Uploaded Files</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
                @Html.Partial("_UploadForm")


                @Html.Partial("_ProcessedFileInfo")

            </div> <!-- Close tab-content-->
        </div><!-- Container close  -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('.nav-tabs a:first').tab('show');
            $('.nav-tabs li a').click(function () { });
            $('.nav-tabs li').hover(function () {
                var liData = $(this);
                $('.hiddenData input:hidden').val(liData.find('a').text());
            });
            if ($('.hiddenData input:hidden').val() != '') {
                var liList = $('.tab-container li');
                var hiddenData = $('.hiddenData input:hidden').val();
                liList.each(function () {
                    if ($(this).find('a').text() == hiddenData) {
                        $(this).find('a').click();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I got it working and I'm posting the answer in case anyone needs it in the future. In a nutshell since the Grid.MVC is doing all the postback through jquery and there is no server transfer of values so the tab value couldn't be stored in a hidden field across postbacks. So I went the way of jquery.cookie. below is the final jquery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.nav-tabs a:first').tab('show');
        $('.nav-tabs li').click(function () { });
        $('.nav-tabs li').hover(function () {
            var liData = $(this);
            $.cookie('saved-tab', liData.find('a').text());
        });
        if ($.cookie('saved-tab') != '') {
            var liList = $('.nav-tabs li');
            var hiddenData = $.cookie('saved-tab');
            liList.each(function () {
                if ($(this).find('a').text() == hiddenData) {
                    $(this).find('a').click();
                }
            });
        }
    });

</script>
```